# Notations for dual spaces and dual operators

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, notation, unbounded-operators

I'm asking for opinions about the 'best' notations for:
 1. the algebraic dual of a vector space $X$;
 2. the continuous dual of a TVS;
 3. the algebraic dual (transpose) of an operator $T$ between vector spaces;
 4. the dual (transpose) of a continuous operator between TVS;
 5. the adjoint of a bounded operator $T$ between Hilbert spaces.

My problem is that I would like to use these notions in the same context. The standard notations tend to overlap but I am forced to use different notations for each of these entities. Of course it is easy to come up with notations, but some traditions are well established and it is not trivial to respect them and at the same time keep them apart, with some elegance.

What I'm using now:
 1. $X'_{alg}$
 2. $X'$
 3. $^tT$
 4. $T'$
 5. $T^*$

Thank you for your advice.

Comment: PS how do I make this question a CW?

Comment: One way is to flag for moderator attention (as someone just did).

Comment: Do you really need two different symbols for 3 and 4? When the latter is defined (i.e. $T$ is continuous), it is a restriction of the former.

Comment: Sure, but  if you write the restriction you are also using a different notation for the two objects, and a less elegant one in my opinion

Comment: I have encountered the notations 1. $X'$; 2. $X^*$; 3. $T'$; 4. $T^*$; 5. $T^{\star}$. Notice that there are different stars for 4 and 5.

Comment: Many operator algebraists don't like $E'$ for the dual of $E$ because this is used for the commutant, and one sometimes wants to refer to both the commutant of an algebra and its continuous dual.

Comment: You see $X^*$ and $X'$ for 1 and 2, sometimes one way, sometimes the other.  Neither choice is universal, but both should be understood.  Then use $T^*$ and $T'$ for 3 and 4, in the same order.

Answer (score 5):

The standard notation don't overlap as much as you think if you are careful with types. For example $X'$ is perfectly fine for both 1. and 2. because vector spaces and topological vector spaces are not the same type. Any object $X$ should only have one type so that there can never be any confusion. You can use the same notation if you never forget forgetful functors (i.e. never pretend that a TVS is the same as its underlying vector space). Similarly ' can be used for both 3. and 4.

If you do want to extract the underlying vector space of a TVS some times, you might have an easier time just giving a name to the forgetful functor instead of inventing more notation.

EDIT:

And by the way: You don't *have* to name the forgetful functor $F$ or something similar like Nate used in the comment. You can also name it implicitely, although that solves only half of your problems. Simply stop using the abuse-of-notation $X$ when you mean $(X,\tau)$ for a vector space topology $\tau$ (which we already knew could happen when we introduced this and any other abuse-of-notation. They live only as long as they're useful and don't lead to confusion!) and the functor becomes $(X,\tau)\mapsto X$. Then you can use both $(X,\tau)'$ and $X'$ without confusion. Of course problems 3. and 4. persist.

Comment: Yes, that's one approach. But its danger is that if you insist on explicitly noting all forgetful functors, your notation may become cluttered by unnecessary symbols. For example, if $X$ is a tvs, you cannot write $x\in X$ because $X$ is not a set.

Comment: I do not feel it is elegant to use two different letters for the same set of vectors, as you propose to do (unless I misunderstood)

Comment: Maybe I should clarify that the material I'm writing is for student use, thus I need a notation which is as simple as possible

Comment: While this answer is formally correct, I think it will be extremely confusing to "working mathematicians".

Comment: @NateEldredge I don't think so. This is what most of us are already doing when we're using the same symbol in different contexts. We differentiate between the contexts mostly by using the types of the occurring objects. In this case the two context simply happen to be connected by a forgetful functor.

Comment: Then maybe I have misunderstood your suggestion.  You are suggesting that $X'$ already has a different meaning depending on whether I mean $X$ to be a vector space or a TVS.  So if I have defined $X$ as a TVS, but I wish to speak about its algebraic dual, it seems like you are suggesting I write something like $F[X]'$ where I have previously defined $F$ to be the forgetful functor, so that $F[X]$ is "$X$ as a vector space". I really don't think this sort of thing is common among working mathematicians.

Comment: @user95282 No, not all forgetful functors. Just the ones that are important in context. Alternatively: If I really wanted to make all forgetful functors explicit, I could do that too by overloading symbols like $\in$ some more. If you're gonna do it anyway, why not go big and define $\in$ for all concrete categories!

Comment: @NateEldredge Yes, that's exactly what I'm suggesting. And I would also guess that the reason why you don't see that particular forgetful functor out in the wild is because a. hardly anyone uses both abstract and topological vector spaces at the same time and b. categorial thinking isn't quite as established in the functional analysis community as it is in say algebra. (But it should be!)

Comment: @JohannesHahn It is quite common to distinguish between the algebraic and continuous dual in functional analysis.

Comment: @yuggib Oh course they are distinct. I never said anything to the contrary. I said that one can use the same notation for both.

Comment: @NateEldredge Maybe this will help: Nobody here ever considered (until now) that ' might denote the commutator group although every vector space has an underlying group with is often denoted by the same symbol. That's what I mean by "we're already using type-inference to distinguish between overloaded symbols". We see that $X$ is a vector space and not a group and infer that ' stands for the dual space of a vector space not the commutator of a group. We simply stopped forgetting the forgetful functor and everything worked out. My suggestion is simply doing the same here.

Comment: @JohannesHahn And I am saying that using the same notation for both is extremely confusing. Consider the topologies $\sigma(X',X)$ as opposed to $\sigma(X^*,X)$. The two corresponding topological spaces are different (if $X$ is e.g. a separable Hilbert space, the second is isomorphic to the Hausdorff completion of the first). So it would be a very bad idea to use the same notation for $X'$ and $X^*$.

Comment: @yuggib Exactly! And that's why I advocate for an approach that doesn't have this problem. Following my suggestion, the two topologies would be denoted $\sigma(X',X)$ and $\sigma(F(X)',X)$ or something similar where $F: \textsf{TVS}\to\textsf{Vect}$ is the forgetful functor.

Comment: This solution is consistent with the possibilities listed in the question: When the forgetful functor $TVS\to Vect$ is $X\mapsto X_{alg}$, the algebraic dual of $X$ is $X_{alg}^\prime$, as long as it is understood that this is $(X_{alg})^\prime$, not $(X^\prime)_{alg}$.

Comment: @JohannesHahn I am not convinced, sorry. As objects in $\mathrm{Vect}$, $X′$ and $X^*$ are distinct (their dimensionality may differ, think e.g. of a separable hilbert space); therefore the forgetful functor on $(X′,τ′)$, with $\tau'$ a given topology, would yield $X'$ as a vector space rather than $X^*$.

Comment: Essentially, the point I am trying to make is that $F(X')\ncong X^*$ in general; alternatively, using your notation, that duality and the forgetful functor "do not commute": $F((X,\tau)')\ncong F((X,\tau))'$. Therefore with your notation, $\sigma(X^*,X)$ would have to become $\sigma(F((X,\tau))',X)$; and the latter notation is in my opinion more involved and unintuitive than $X^*$ or $X'_{\mathrm{alg}}$.

Comment: @yuggib But why should anything like that be true? There is no reason to believe that they do commute or "should" commute in the first place. That's the whole reason why we distinguish between algebraic and continuous dual! Exactly the point you've started with in other words. You can't have it both ways ;-)

Comment: @JohannesHahn I am just saying that such notation becomes rather inconvenient in my opinion, and could easily lead to confusion. It is sufficient to misplace a parenthesis or a prime to change the space we are dealing with; and  in addition it is rather cumbersome. Using two different symbols or a subscript makes it easier to distinguish the two duals, even at a quick glance.

Answer (score 5):

Given your situation of having to juggle all these notational traditions at the same time, I would recommend for a space $X$ and an operator $A$:

1. $X^{\vee}$, 2. $X'$, 3. $A^{\rm T}$, 4. $A^{\rm T}$, 5. $A^*$

My rationale is as follows.

For 1: **Algebraic** geometers especially use the "vee' notation for the algebraic dual so I think the cultural association helps the brain automatically make the association with the algebraic notion of dual.

For 2: One usually does not write the space of tempered distributions as $S^*(\mathbb{R}^d)$ but rather as $S'(\mathbb{R^d})$.

For 3 and 4: I would use the same notation as per the comment by user95282 since the maps are related by restriction. One could use ${}^{\rm t}A$ for both but I prefer the matrix algebra notation if only because it is easier to type.

For 5: As yuggib said, it is standard in the theory of $C^*$-algebras and spectral theory. I don't see any reason to be a contrarian and not follow what everyone else does.

Comment: This is an interesting suggestion

Comment: sorry it came a bit late.

Answer (score 2):

I like the notation $T^*$ for the adjoint, since it agrees with the usual notation for the involution of *-algebras. I don't know however if I would distinguish between $^t T$ and its continuous version with an *ad hoc* notation.

For algebraic and continuous duals of (topological) vector spaces, personally I like Bourbaki's notation $X^*$ for the algebraic dual and $X'$ for the continuous dual (even if $X_{\prime}$ for preduals is afwul, as opposed to $X_*$ that is natural if $X^*$ is the continuous dual). In addition, if $X$ is also a (subset of some) *-algebra, the notation $X^*$ may yield some confusion.